# Converting data destined for a pandas.series to a clean array

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I need to create three `pandas.Series` (x, y, z). The data for this is formatted in various ways. Some are separated by `\n` and `;`, some are separated using only spaces.  I want a generalized approach for extracting this data into a list.  The data looks something like:

```
x is "\n -10.03 -7.02 -0.05 9.96 20 40"
y is "\n 0.70;\n 0.79;\n 0.90;\n 1.00"
z is "\n 100.00 100.00 100.00 100.00 100.00 100.00;\.." (24 times)
```

Comment: you have 3 or 4 questions in it, kindly split them into several posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using a regular expression and a list comprehension:

**Code:**

```
import re
split_pattern = re.compile(r'[\n \t;]+')

x = '\n -10.03 -7.02 -0.05 9.96 20 40'
y = '\n 0.70;\n 0.79;\n 0.90;\n 1.00'
z = '\n 100.00 100.00 100.00 100.00 100.00 100.00;'

for data in (x, y, z):
    data_list = [float(d) for d in split_pattern.split(data) if d != ""]
    print(data_list)
```

**Results:**

```
[-10.03, -7.02, -0.05, 9.96, 20.0, 40.0]
[0.7, 0.79, 0.9, 1.0]
[100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I wanted for now. Sorry to make this question not clear at first. :)